# Is there a way to input the data of multiple content types all on the same page?

Tags: 8

I have three content types: `student`, `course`, and `student_takes_course` (`student_takes_course` have two reference fields that points to the `student` and `course` content types).

To input a new `student_takes_course` record, I would first have to go to the `student` content type and input a new `student` record, and then go to the `course` content type and input a new `course` record, and only then I can go to the `student_takes_course` content type and input a new record that have references to the newly inputted `student` and `course` records).

But is there a way to input the `student` and `course` and `student_takes_course` records all on the same page?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the module [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) as widget for student and course in your student-course content type.

This widget loads the node form for student and course in student-course content creation form, so you can fill all the data in the same place.